# Problems with Google Sheets importxml

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import data from the Bscscan: https://bscscan.com/address/0x2ceDA5cf32A34702D342f0DedA0af298C1BD8049 to Google Sheets, using the formula =IMPORTXML(A1,A2), ie:

A1= https://bscscan.com/address/0x2ceDA5cf32A34702D342f0DedA0af298C1BD8049

A2= //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "mb-md-0", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "align-items-center", " " )) and (((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 1) and parent::*)]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "col-md-8", " " ))]

The problem is that every time it shows an error that says that is not possible to fetch url. I only have problems with this website, can someone please help me?

Comment: Take a look here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.